# Extract a tar file with no directory information

Tags: bash, tar

I have a folder I am turning into a tar file for transfer over the network it looks like this

```
/foo/bar/file1
/foo/file2
/foo/baz/bin/file3
```

I want to extract it with no directory information so the extracted contents look like this

```
file1
file2
file3
```

How does one accomplish this

Comment: Which tar are you using to extract?

Comment: Make sure you don't get conflicting filenames...

Comment: Not a programming question. `How to use a computer`-questions belong on superuser.

Comment: It's programming if it's part of a script, or if the best answer involves programming / scripting.

Comment: I intend to disagree. If [`How do I remove a file in Linux whose name looks like it's ONLY a hyphen, as in “-”`](http://superuser.com/questions/347505/how-do-i-remove-a-file-in-linux-whose-name-looks-like-its-only-a-hyphen-as-in) is superuser, this is too. But to be nice: tar has a `--strip-components` ...

Answer (score 2):

[The GNU tar manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html) elaborates on --transform:

```
tar --show-transformed --transform 's,.*/,,' tfv myarchive.tar 
tar --transform 's,.*/,,' xf myarchive.tar
```

Comment: This will still create the directories, though, it will just not populate them.

Answer (score 1):

What about the Unix philosophy of stringing together tools?
Use tar to extract as usual, then

```
find foo -type f | xargs mv '{}' .
rm -rf foo  # optional, nuke the empty dirs.
```

or variations thereof with `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0`.